# Server access Error: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException on macOS Big Sur

Tags: scala, ssl-certificate, sbt

I am on macOS Big Sur and I am using EAA as my corporate VPN.

Whenever I run sbt I get this error stack trace.

```
> sbt clean compile
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/shril/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/shril/Documents/repos/my_repos/AudiencePayloadSpark/project
[error] Server access Error: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.14.10/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.14.10/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.10_0.13/0.14.10/sbt-assembly-0.14.10.pom
[warn]  module not found: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.10
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.14.10/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.14.10/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/shril/.ivy2/local/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.14.10/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.10_0.13/0.14.10/sbt-assembly-0.14.10.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.10: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I have tried importing certificates and adding to my keychain. But nothing is helping.

```
openssl x509 -in <(openssl s_client -connect repo.typesafe.com:443 -prexit 2>/dev/null) -out ~/repo-typesafe.crt
sudo keytool -importcert -file ~/repo-typesafe.crt -alias repo.typesafe.com -keystore /Users/shril/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

My java version is openjdk version "1.8.0_332" and I use sdkman.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything for SBT to work with these repositories as the HTTPS certificate should be already considered valid by default by your system/Java.

Comment: Maybe you're behind some kind of proxy or your VPN manipulates HTTPS certificate that is presented to you?

Comment: My corporate setup includes the Akamai EAA client. But I tried shutting it down and re-running sbt. Still it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue uploading files to a protected nexus maven repository even though I've updated my sdkman java candidate keystore with my corporate certificate.
Try explicitly specifying the trustStore.

```
mvn -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=home/docker/.sdkman/candidates/java/18.0.1-open/lib/security/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<<your password>> -Dmaven.repo.local=/opt/develWorkspace/Maven/repository -U -X install -f pom.xml -s /opt/develWorkspace/Maven/settings.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. You need to set `SSL Certificates for NetSkope` for Java to solve this problem.